# Initializing gradient boosting with the sample mean

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, boosting, gradient

[image]

For gradient boosting in the regression setting, the final vector of fitted values is
$$F_M(x) = \bar{y} + \rho_1h_1(x) + \ldots, + \rho_M h_M(x)$$

Suppose I have a new data set $x_{new}$ that I'd like to make predictions on. Are my predicted values the following:

$$F_M(x_{new}) = \bar{y} + \rho_1h_1(x_{new}) + \ldots, + \rho_M h_M(x_{new})$$

My question is, am I also adding the sample mean of my responses in my training data, $\bar{y}$ to the final set of predictions on this new data set?

Comment: Yes, we do. Notice that the mean if simply $F_0(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We take the mean as the "best first guess" and then keep adding terms to try and correct the errors of the model so far.

When we use this model to make predictions, we don't just need the error correction terms, but we also need the same initial guess. So we use the $\bar{y}$ from the training set.